# What does this preg_match syntax match ".+?"

Tags: php, regex

I know perl style regular expresions fairly well, but today I found one that I do not understand:

```
preg_match('/^On.+?wrote:.+?$/i',$line); //reduced example
```

What does the `.+?` mean? I undarstand the `.+` alone, I understand `.?` alone. But `.+?`? It seems a bug to me.

The line should match popular citation prefixes in the email body and it is much more complicated along with look behinds, but this is the only part i can't understand, and still the regexp seems to work correclty.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19405163/476

Comment: See also [stackoverflow.com/questions/13705478](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705478/what-is-the-difference-between-the-regex-and/13705682#13705682)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` means one or more and is greedy. `+?` means the same, it just is not greedy like usual regex are.

Edit: I wanted to explain it a little further, but the comment of deceze already explains enough.^^

Comment: That simple. Face palm. I should have known that... Thank you :-)

Comment: @SWilk regex are pretty complicated, i don't think its a reason to facepalm just because you didn't recognize a syntax immediately. I got my regex cheatsheet next to me all time because i always forget something. :)

Comment: Yeah, but I was "our local regexp guru" at the office. And I have used much more advanced and unreadable features. And now I have stumbled upon some basic ungreedeness. Nothing happend, just some ego injured ;)

Answer (score 2):

In short, when you add `?` its matching least amount possible, where as without `?` its matching most amount possible:

Here is the explanation:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy not Greedy

> .+? matches any character (except newline)
>
> ```
> Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
> ```

check at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: Wheres the difference? Lazy and not greedy actually mean the same. They only take as much as they need to fulfill the condition.

Comment: I mean it's **Lazy** `.+?` instead of **Greedy** `.+`

Comment: Oh. Well, that's right. Sorry, it was a long day, i have lost my ability to think. :D